# Interpolation of string while appending values to array in Python

Tags: python-2.7

Suppose I have some arrays initialized named as hi, bi, ci. Like in Perl we have this curly braces {} for interpolating strings inside the name of variable names. How to do it in python?

```
hi_name = []
bi_name = []
ci_name = []

temp = ["hi", "bi", "ci"]

for i in temp:
  {i}_name.append("abc")  # How to accomplish this in Python

print hi, bi, ci
```

Or Is there any Other way I can do the above thing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: While possible, you don't want to do this. Better to make a dict called `name` that you can access with `name['hi']`, `name['bi']`, etc.